# Line/load matching for electric power transmission

Tags: power, transmission-line, impedance-matching, microwave

Impedance matching is a critical topic for microwave engineering where the signal wavelength becomes comparable to the physical sizes of components. Substitution of distributed component models for standard lumped component models leads to circuit equations involving wave reflections, VSWR, s-parameters, and all that fun stuff.

Do these topics translate to the electric power industry where voltage and current waves must travel over extremely long lengths of power lines? It seems to me that these topics are not very prominent in power engineering, or am I mistaken? Consider a very simple model of a generator connected to a step-up transformer, which connects to a load through a step-down transformer by means of many kilometres of power line. It's impossible for the designer to predict the load at the end of the line, unlike in microwave engineering where the load is practically guaranteed to be 50 Ohms. So, how can the designer perform impedance matching to eliminate reflections? If this is a non-issue in the power industry, why is  it a non-issue?

Comment: On the contrary, the wavelength of 50 Hz is 600 km and at 300 km you will get total voltage waveform inversion so you need to be very concious of the effects of line length.

Comment: To expand a bit on Andy's comment - very long High Voltage AC (there are HVDC lines too) transmission lines require substations along the path whose sole function is the shift of the waveform's phase so it matches the phase of the power at the endpoint.